# Unity plugin not working in OpenGL 4.1, working with OpenGL 2.1

Tags: c#, c, opengl, unity-game-engine

I have a question regarding a small Unity plugin I'm writing.

The plugin takes a Unity3D Texture2D and tries to update it, the compiled plugin works when running Unity3D with `-force-opengl` (to run in OpenGL 2.1), but it's not working when running in normal mode (OpenGL 4.1). Is there anything that I'm missing?

The plugin should update the internal OpenGL texture and set it's data. The plugin does not crash the game or anything, but the texture does update when running on 2.1, but just shows a gray texture in 4.1

In Unity's own sample they're using GLEW for initialising an OpenGL context (https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/graphicsdemos/src/548c5251ddbe82129b2584992a0f50caa4c34c6c/NativeRenderingPlugin/PluginSource/source/RenderAPI_OpenGLCoreES.cpp?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)
But shouldn't an OpenGL context already exist in the plugin? Is there any difference between the OpenGL versions regarding that?

I'm running on OSX El Capitan.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**C plugin code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>

#include "unity/IUnityInterface.h"

#include "debug.c"

void RenderTexture (void* texId, int time) {
    GLuint gltex = (GLuint)(size_t)(texId);

    int id, i, j;
    GLubyte img[64 * 64 * 4];

    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
            id = (4 * j) + (4 * 64 * i);
            img[id] = (GLubyte) time % 255;
            img[id + 1] = (GLubyte) time % 255;
            img[id + 2] = (GLubyte) (255 - time) % 255;
            img[id + 3] = (GLubyte) (255 - time) % 255;
        }
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gltex);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 64, 64, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
}
```

**C# Unity code**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class TestBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    [DllImport("main")]
    private static extern void RenderTexture (IntPtr ptrTexture, int time);

    Texture2D tex;

    void Start () {
        tex = new Texture2D (64, 64, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
        tex.Apply ();

        GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.SetTexture ("_MainTex", tex);
    }

    void Update () {
        RenderTexture (tex.GetNativeTexturePtr (), (int)Time.realtimeSinceStartup * 10);
    }

}
```

Comment: "it's not working"  Segfault?  Kernel panic?  Deletes your home directory?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really add a correct description of "not working" indeed, I've updated the question. Basically I want the texture to update it's data, which it does on OpenGL 2.1, but not when running on 4.1 (in which it just displays a gray texture)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OpenGLCoreDetails.html), it seems that using `-force-opengl` with Unity uses legacy OpenGL.  Try it with `-force-glcore` and see if you get a different result.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put that command in conditional, like

```
if (version <= 2.1) then       -force-opengl
```

so, it wont be executed in new **OpenGL**

Answer (score 0):

I will not pretend to truly help, but I cannot comment, so.

First things first: it's really weird how you use ARGB format in your C# code and RGBA in C code. Mistake or am I getting something wrong?

Second thing - you're not even trying to understand what actually went wrong.
Use `GLenum error = glGetError();` to get the latest possible error that happened in OpenGL state machine, then check out the [glTexSubimage2d documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) to see a list of possible errors and their causes. Following those simple steps might help you understand what you did wrong and if you didn't do anything wrong then it's Unity side problem.

In fact, there are so many possible causes of this problem that no glError information just leaves you with no hope of further investigation.